# Creating a thread Pool for boost threads

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, threadpool, boost-thread

There seems to be two approaches to create thread pool for boost threads as boost thread does not provide thread pool directly.

The first one is

```
    asio::io_service io_service;
    asio::io_service::work work(io_service);
    boost::thread_group threads;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < my_thread_count; ++i)
        threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&asio::io_service::run, &io_service));

    io_service.post(boost::bind(an_expensive_calculation, 42));
    io_service.post(boost::bind(a_long_running_task, 123));

    io_service.stop();
    threads.join_all();
```

The second one is using unofficial thread pool from here http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/

```
     void taskfunc();

     // later on...
     pool my_pool;
     my_pool.schedule(&taskfunc);
```

My question is which is a better approach among these two here? Are there any specific advantages of either over each other? Thanks..

Comment: What do you mean *better approach*? Your criteria is not clear.